# Liquibase diff generating forIndexName doesn't work on h2

Tags: hibernate, h2, liquibase

I'm running Liquibase 3.5.3 and using Liquibase for handling the changes in the DB.
Is it possible in some way to make the Liquibase diff command not generate the forIndexName when adding a primary key?
ChangeSets with this forIndexName fails on at least h2 where I get the error:

*forIndexName is not allowed on h2*

So it would be nice not needing to remove this attribute always from the generated changelog.

Answer (score 0):

`forIndexName` is not supported on H2 for now.

As a workaround, you can use liquibase *3.3.5* which is liquibase last version which generates changelog without the `forIndexName` instruction.

Changelog file generated with an old liquibase version can be loaded with a liquibase newer version.